# How to insert kendo drop down list into kendo grid, but with a different data source?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I've created a kendo grid, and need to insert kendo drop down into one of the columns. I need to get the data for the drop down from another data source. It kind of works, however, the problem is when I have chosen a value from the drop down and the drop down closes, instead of displaying that value it goes into editable mode. Only when I click outside of the dropdown, it displays the correct value. Here is a gif of the issue:

https://media2.giphy.com/media/KyMGB7FmFQMVTChFA7/giphy.gif

How could this issue be solved?

I have successfully created a kendo grid with a drop down list already. The only difference seems to be that there only one data source is used, but here two are used. Here is some of the code for the drop down:

````
  title: "Type",
  field: "productType.name", //this property is from the data source used for grid
  template: "<kendo-drop-down-list k-value=\"dataItem.productType.id\" 
    k-options=\"productTypeOptions\" ng-change=\"productTypeChanged(dataItem, 'productType')\" 
    ng-model=\"dataItem.productType.id\"></kendo-drop-down-list>"
}...];

$scope.productTypes = {
  data: [{ name: "Value 1", id: "1" }, { name: "Value 2", id: "2" }]
}

$scope.productTypeDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  schema: {
    data: "data",
    model: {
      fields: {
      id: { type: "number" },
      name: { type: "string" }
      }
    }
  },
  data: $scope.productTypes,
  serverPaging: true,
  serverSorting: true,
  serverFiltering: true
});

$scope.productTypeOptions = {
  dataSource: $scope.productTypeDataSource,
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "id"
};

$scope.productTChanged = function (dataItem, field, productArray, dataSource) {
  var index = dataSource.indexOf(dataItem);
  var c = productArray.data[index];
  if (c == null) return;
  c[field] = dataItem[field];
  return c;
};

$scope.productTypeChanged = function (dataItem, field) {
  $scope.productTChanged(dataItem, field, $scope.products, $scope.productDataSource);
};```
````